# Closed formula for the numbers of the form $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{9}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, nested-radicals

how can i find the formula for the nth term of this series?

SQ = square root

$\sqrt{1} = 1$

$\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{4}} = \sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{4+\sqrt{9}}} \approx 1.909385061$

$\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{4+\sqrt{9+\sqrt{16}}}} \approx 1.938508807$

$\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{4+\sqrt{9+\sqrt{16+\sqrt{25}}}}} \approx 1.942232028$

$\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{4+\sqrt{9+\sqrt{16+\sqrt{25+\sqrt{36}}}}}} \approx 1.942619065$

$\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{4+\sqrt{9+\sqrt{16+\sqrt{25+\sqrt{36+\sqrt{49}}}}}}} \approx 1.942652736$

Comment: I doubt, that there is a nice formular. With the second inner square root you get an irrational number, and the other square roots make it even worse.

Comment: Convergence seems pretty quick here. The 36th element in the sequence is about 1.942655422764. I tried plugging that into an inverse symbolic calculator, and it didn't find anything.

Comment: Most of the numbers you give on the right hand side are rational approximations of irrational numbers. So we don't write $\pi = 3.14$ but $\pi \approx 3.14$ (unless we're making one of those dumbed down standardized tests).

Comment: A closed form expression for $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$$ isn't even known:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html

Comment: $a_1 = \sqrt{1^2}$

$a_2 = \sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2}}$

$a_3 = \sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2}}}$

and so on.

If we want to find $a_n$, let us try to express it in terms of $a_{n-1}$ since it doesn't have a closed form, I think.

Try expressing $a_2$ in terms of $a_1$ and then $a_3$ in terms of $a_2$ until you see a pattern.

I think.

Or is the point that there is no pattern?

Comment: What is the final answer here ?